# I don't want to get "proposed change" notifications

Tags: support, documentation, notifications

Sometimes, I get "proposed change" notifications, but I don't want to get the notifications. Can I let it not send me "proposed change" notifications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can visit [your watch list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=documentation&sort=watching) and remove anything you aren't interested in.

I see you are watching all discussions on a number of topics in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java) and [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android). If you want to watch something other than proposed changes, you can toggle those notifications there too.