# Community Wiki for Documentation

Tags: support, documentation

Is there an option to make my contributions to the Documentation project community wiki (or similar)?

I had a quick play with it, decided it was yet more write only information and moved on. Unfortunately I get notifications when the stuff I wrote gets edited etc. I'm really not interested and don't want to be bothered by this stuff.

Comment: You can unwatch topics or tags, if that's what you're talking about. I believe everyone is opted-in by default when they edit a page. Look for the 'eye' icon somewhere on the tag summary page of the tag you edited.

Comment: I also don't like these notifications much. Maybe a setting like "Don't get notified on changes to contributions to Documentation" would be sufficient to solve this problem.

Comment: I clicked the unwatch. I'll see what happens.

Comment: @Iain I just updated something you've previously edited; let's see if you get any notifications...

Comment: Your title really has nothing to do with the main point about notifications, which is a dupe of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344538/ Fyi, the eye Tyler mentioned can also be found in the documentation tab of your profile.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation already functions as Community Wiki, in the sense that posts aren't owned by a single person, and anyone is free to edit (or suggest edits) that actually change the content, and aren't obligated to maintain the intent, voice, etc. of the author(s).  They're designed, from the ground up, to be collaboratively edited, unlike non-CW posts on main sites.

If you simply don't want notifications for content you've provided, you could disassociate your account from that content (which is very different from what CW does on questions/answers).  You can flag your content or use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page and request that a certain content be disassociate from your account.

Comment: "If you simply don't want notifications for content you've provided, you could disassociate your account from that content ..." If this is the recommended way, it may be good to automatize this at some point. Like if, in my profile, I could easily disassociate myself from any content I'm currently associated with with a single click.

Comment: Is there actual mod tooling for Docs dissociation yet?

Comment: "Documentation already functions as Community Wiki" I guess this isn't _true_. When I edit some Doc post and it gets accepted I get +2. Whereas, for the Community Wiki I will not get any reputation.

Comment: @Shashanth The *purpose* of CW is not to remove reputation.  The *purpose* of CW is to indicate that the post is a collaborative effort of many people, and that anyone is welcome to come along and change the *content* of the post if they think they have something to add, unlike a normal SO answer in which it is not appropriate to do that (you add your own answer if you have your own original contribution to make).  That CW posts don't give rep is a side effect of the fact that they didn't come up with a way to deal with giving rep to multiple authors.

Comment: @Servy Thank you for the explanation. Sorry, I had little confusion with the starting line of your post.